# Mean and variance for a Binomial distribution.

Tags: probability

[image]

I found a proof http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Binomial_Distribution but the question here asks to consider differenciation (see hint) how do I do that?

$$E[X] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x \left( 
\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}
\right)
p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$$

In the hint theres only a $\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}
\right)
p^{x}$ part. What happened to the rest of the terms?

**UPDATE 1**

Ok so I got up to here, 1st I replaced $x$ with $k$ so

$$E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^n k \left( 
\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}
\right) \left(  \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^k (1-p)^n$$

Then I let $x = \frac{p}{1-p}$. (what do I do with the $(1-p)^k$ tho, I cant remove the $p$ term with this substitution?)

$$=(1-p)^n \sum_{k=0}^n k \left( 
\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}
\right) x^k$$

Seems like I did the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$ E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^n k \left({n \atop k}\right) (1-p)^{n-k} p^k .$$
That is, many places you put an $x$ where you should use a different letter like $k$.

Next, to use from the formula you will get by differentiating, set $x = \frac p{1-p}$, and then multiply both sides by $p(1-p)^{n-1}$.

Comment: When you say multiply both sides which sides do you mean?

Comment: You differentiate both sides of the equation given in the hint.  You make the substitution into the resulting equation, and then multiply both sides as I suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. But I am still a little confused, see update 1 of OP

Comment: You are doing things in the wrong order.  First differentiate the hint w.r.t. $x$.  Then make the substitution.  Then see how this gives what you want (i.e. how close is it to $E[X]$).

Comment: Also $$\left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^k (1-p)^n = p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$

Comment: So I differenciated the hint and got $\sum_k = \left( \begin{array}{c}n \\
k \end{array} \right)kx^{k-1}=-n(1-x)^{n-1}$. Then in the expectation equation I have $\sum_k k \left( \begin{array}{c}n \\
k \end{array} \right) x^{k-1} x (1-p)^n = (-n(1-x)^{n-1})(x (1-p)^n)$ which seems wrong ... sorry I must have did something wrong again ...

Comment: The differentiation was correct.  Then you need to substitute $x=\frac p{1-p}$.  Note that $1-x = \frac1{1-p}$.  Then I was wrong about what you multiply it by - it is $p(1-p)^{n-1}$.  But don't do the multiplication until you have completely substituted for $x$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11721/discussion-between-jiew-meng-and-stephen-montgomery-smith)

Comment: I just comment here since latex doesnt seem to work in chat: $1-x=\frac{1}{1-p}$ how do you get this? Cos $1-\frac{1}{1-p}=x$ then $x=\frac{-p}{1-p}$ isit?

Comment: I was wrong.  $1+x = \frac 1{1-p}$.  Sorry.  We are probably in different time zones, so I don't know how well chat will work.

Comment: Ah... ok actually I believe the differntiation of hint should become $\sum_k \left( \begin{array}{c}n \\
k \end{array} \right)kx^{k-1}=n(1+x)^{n-1}$ apart from that everything works fine now. Thanks